# systemd debug (embedded case)

Tags: systemd, embedded, debugging, systemd-unit

How to trace systemd unit files, to be specific, device unit files? I use 3.18 version of linux kernel. On my board after systemd has started, (mypartition).device runs and, I suppose, remounts the rootfs and it takes about 2 seconds to complete as systemd-analyze plot shows. I want to know what it does during those 2 seconds, because remounting of rootfs takes not so much time (usually few milliseconds). How I can understand systemd-analyze plot, there are so many unit files, is it possible to know which unit causes running of the others? I tried to find .device unit file in my system, but I could not find anything.

Answer (score 2):

Kernel version 3.18 was released in December 2014, so it's quite old. It was one of the Long-Term Support kernels and may still receive irregular updates from Greg Kroah-Hartman even though the "official" End-Of-Life for this kernel version was in January 2017. Because of this, the kernel version is not necessarily a reliable indicator of the age of any other OS components anyway, especially on embedded systems.

What does your system report with `systemctl --version`?

On modern versions of systemd, filesystem mounting is handled by the `*.mount` units. Specifically, to view the contents of the root filesystem mount unit, `-.mount`, you'll need `systemctl cat -- -.mount` to force the interpretation of `-.mount` as a unit name (instead of an option). With that command, you should see that the mount unit will have an automatic `After=` ordering dependency on the device/target representing the device containing the root filesystem.

The `*.device` units appear as a device is detected by the kernel and gains its representation in the `/sys` virtual filesystem and the `udev`-maintained device nodes (when applicable, e.g. network devices are handled without device nodes).

The `*.device` units are typically all autogenerated, so you won't normally find any `*.device` unit files anywhere. Instead, udev rules may influence the creation of a device unit: for example, if an udev rule sets the property `SYSTEMD_READY=0` for a device, the device creation is omitted until that property is removed or changed to `SYSTEMD_READY=1`. See `man systemd.device` for more details.

Essentially, the `*.device` units exist to represent hardware devices, mostly so that other units will be able to define dependencies on them. By default, the device units won't depend on any other units; instead, they will by definition "depend" on the userspace-accessible device they represent.

The 2 seconds you're seeing might be from any combination of the following operations:

- detection and preparation of the bus that contains the disk controller (if applicable for your system architecture)
- detection and resetting of the disk controller itself
- detection and resetting of the disk(s) as the Linux kernel driver takes over control of it, to get the disk into a known state after whatever operations the system firmware may have already done with it (this probably takes the most of the 2 seconds, as disks may have extensive internal self-test routines they'll run at reset)
- reading, identifying and processing the partition table on the disk (the Linux kernel supports several partition table formats: depending on hardware architecture, more than one of them might be applicable)

Comment: systemd version is 230.  Unfortunately there is no any "After=" field, only "Before=local-fs.target" in "-.mount" unit file. So you say that there is nothing to do for mounting in *.device unit files, right? Is it possible to find out what exactly systemd does during those 2 seconds on mypartition.device (which is the partition for rootfs)  by any means, debugging systemd, ftracing or anything, and how can I do it?

Comment: There is normally no unit *file* for device units. The device units are dynamically generated in RAM according to udev events. You might want to look at `dmesg` output and udev rules to find out how much time is taken by hardware detection, and/or if there are any extra steps dictated by udev rules, like attempting to detect software RAID members or LVM volume groups on any detected block devices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that was plentiful. Could you tell me which function of systemd is responsible for calculating "Activating" time in systemd-analyze plot and functions for creation of the device unit files and parsing them? (the source code of systemd looks very obscure for me, so far I could not find the right entry point).